# roslaunch cannot find node executable

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an ROS node called `bag_player_controller` inside a package which is also called `bag_player_controller`. In another ROS package within the same catkin workspace, I have the following lines:

```
<node name="bag_player_controller" pkg="bag_player_controller" type="bag_player_controller" output="screen" required="false">   
    <!-- name of the bag player node to control -->     
    <param type="str" name="player_name" value="bag_player"/>

</node>
```

But when I run the launch file, I get this error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home.net/aa17gil/work/mapper/src/bag_player_controller/bag_player_controller'

For some reason, ROS is searching for the executable inside the `src` directory. But when I do `rosrun bag_player_controller bag_player_controller`, it runs fine. Also, when I run `catkin_find bag_player_controller bag_player_controller`, it gives the correct path to the executable inside `devel/RelWithDebInfo/lib/bag_player_controller/bag_player_controller`, so I don't think there's a problem with my CMakeLists.txt, or my environment.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264866/roslaunch-cannot-find-node-executable/) by [Ali250](https://answers.ros.org/users/24947/ali250/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-06-28**:
This is strange, because your node clearly is assigned to your package.
Can you try only typing

just to test if that works?
I'm fairly new to ROS, but I launch all my executables that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve the problem. For some reason (build related or my own doing some time earlier), there was a broken symlink to the executable file inside my src folder. Once I deleted that, the launch file started working fine. I guess the important take-away here is that when you launch a node from a launch file, it does actually look inside your src folder for the executable before moving onto the devel/lib folder.

---

Originally posted by [Ali250](https://answers.ros.org/users/24947/ali250/) with karma: 41 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-29**:
you should do this command before roslaunch :

$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

~/catkin_ws/$ source devel/setup.bash

~/catkin_ws/$ catkin_make

~/catkin_ws/$ roslaunch  <launch_file>

**Comment by [MohammedHyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/30707/mohammedhyder/) on 2017-06-29**:
A naive solution is to copy the executable and paste it in the src directory.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-30**:
Guys: thanks for the additional suggestions, but "copying binaries to the src directory" is obviously *not* a solution, it's at best a work-around (and one that should be avoided).

@أسامة الادريسي : you have the `catkin_make` and `source` steps reversed.